# migrate from grails 3.0.4 to 3.0.6

Tags: grails

What is the simplest way to migrate a Grails app developed in 3.0.4 to 3.0.6?

The grails documentation recommends to create a new app and migrate every component one by one. But there should be a simple way if we are migrating within version 3?

Any help much appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I run a `grails create-app` to create a fresh install of the new version.  I then copy the files from the new version over top of my older v3 version.  It's then pretty simple using version control tools to check for changes that need to be merged.  The following files will have some changes that need to be merged into my existing project files:

1. build.gradle
2. gradle.properties

To be safe I usually also copy over the following, though they are less likely to have changes:

1. gradle/
2. gradlew
3. gradlew.bat
4. grails-app/conf/application.yml
5. grails-app/conf/logback.groovy
6. grails-app/i18n/messages.properties
7. grails-app/init//Application.groovy

With version control it usually takes less than a few minutes to review and merge back any changes that need to be retained.  I find the process fairly simple.

Answer (score 0):

I think you refer to this documentation https://grails.github.io/grails-doc/latest/guide/upgrading.html which is really about grails 2.x to 3.0.x migration.

In the case you're already on 3.0.4 you can just look at the [release note of the version](https://github.com/grails/grails-core/releases) to see what is new and if there's any impact. As you will see its a lot of bug fixes and the introduction of the new web profile to create REST specific applications.